# how can i select value from react dropdown using selenium python?

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, selenium-webdriver

I am doing website testing in selenium python. I am not able to select a value from the dropdown. Can anyone help me to do that?

This is my website source code.
[image: This is my website source code.]
when expanding dropdown it does not show value in the DOM so how can I select state Alaska?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the attachment, text box accepts input and filters dropdown list based on our input..To handle these cases:

1. You can use Actions class to handle this.
   Actions(driver).click(element).sendKeys("Alaska").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();

Here, we are communicating with search box cum dropdown and entering "Alaska" in it. Once it entered, it filters the results and display only Alaska in the dropdown.
Later Keys.ENTER just performs ENTER operation which will select the first record in the dropdown list.

2. Use text to identify WebElement. First click on dropdown and write generic xpath like '//*[text()='Alaska']'. This solution may or may not work. But solution 1 is recommendable..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Dropdown does not accept inputs

Comment: In that case, you can prefer second approach. But first wait for the element to load and then click on element using text()

Comment: I have already tried a second approach that's not working. Let me know if anything new

Comment: Can you share the link which you are accessing?

Comment: this is private so I can not give you credentials. but I have attached a video please check it if you get any idea: https://www.loom.com/share/66524c4bb1e74868ac8384c430fc2d9f

Comment: After looking into the video attached, I have observed a new HTML component loading when we clicked on dropdown <div class="select-menu-outer" >...</div>. In Reactjs, if we try to expand this element, it disappears automatically. To overcome this problem, write an xpath like '//div[@class='select-menu-outer']//*[text()='Alaska']'. Before performing click operation on this xpath, wait for element using WebDriverWait and then click on it. This xpath generally matches with text Alaska which is being any child of class="select-menu-outer".

Comment: In case Alaska is not a text in child element, try with '//div[@class='select-menu-outer']//*[@value='Alaska']', This can match for an element attribute value set with Alaska.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="Select a state"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="Select-menu-outer"]//*[@aria-label="Alaska"]').click()
        #state.click()
        time.sleep(5)` Above code that i have write and it will select value as "Arizona" insted of "Alaska".

This is the  class="select-menu-outer" [https://ibb.co/m6Vs2mk] how will this happen any idea? I have already tried `//*[@value='Alaska']` `//*[@id="react-select-2--option-1"]` and `//*[text()='Alaska']`

Comment: Hi @KrupalVaghasiya I do not find any content in the link you shared.. Have you tried this driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="Select-menu-outer"]//*[text()="Alaska"]').click() ?

Comment: Hi @Sreenivasulu, I have tried that, and please check it:https://ibb.co/m6Vs2mk

Comment: Hi @KrupalVaghasiya Hope, your issue resolved.

Comment: Hi @Sreenivasulu Not yes sir, it is not resolved. I have attached a screenshot link of DOM Please check it. `//*[@value='Alaska']` `//*[@id="react-select-2--option-1"]` `//*[text()='Alaska']` and also `//div[@class="Select-menu-outer"]//*[text()="Alaska"]').click()`
It will not select expected value

Comment: Hi @KrupalVaghasiya After clicking on dropdown, add 2-3 seconds hard timeout and click on this element- //div[@class="Select-menu-outer"]//*[text()="Alaska"]. Azizona might select as dropdown loading slowly..

Comment: Hi, @Sreenivasulu Thank you for giving your expansive time. You have solved my problem, thank  you